# Determing type of DataTable event in C++

Tags: c++, events, inheritance, datatable

I am creating an inheritance model for event handling (particularly for `DataTables` and `XmlNode`).

I have a super class called `EventManager` with the following virtual functions:

```
DataChanged(EventArgs *arg)
DataChanging(EventArgs *arg)
DataInserted(EventArgs *arg)
DataInserting(EventArgs *arg)
DataRemoved(EventArgs *arg)
DataRemoving(EventArgs *arg)
```

and also derived classes `DataTableManager` and `XmlNodeManager`.

`DataTable` event arguments vary (e.g. `DataRowChangeEventArgs` and `DataColumnEventArgs`). If the event arg was casted to an `EventArgs` for the parameter, how can I determine the original type once in the derived class, i.e. how can I know if the parameter passed was originally a `DataRowChangeEventArgs` or a `DataColumnEventArgs`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, you should invoke derived-class functionality using virtual functions. However, if you really must test for a type, do this:

```
DataRowChangeEventArgs* foo = dynamic_cast<DataRowChangeEventArgs*>(arg);
if (foo) {
    // is a DataRowChangeEventArgs
}
```

Of course, you can also roll that into a single line:

```
if (DataRowChangeEventArgs* foo = dynamic_cast<DataRowChangeEventArgs*>(arg)) {
    // is a DataRowChangeEventArgs
}
```

(If you've used C# at all, a `dynamic_cast` on a pointer is pretty much like the `as` operator in C#---it returns a pointer to the target type if appropriate, otherwise null.)

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "invoke derived-class functionality using virtual functions". I thought I was using virtual functions.. (unless that is not what you meant by your statement?)

Comment: @developer: Often times, you don't need to know the "real" type of an object---any functionality specific to its type is implemented in a virtual function, so you only need to call that. However, if for some reason you need to get a pointer to the derived type, `dynamic_cast` is the way to do it.

Comment: ah.. I think I understand what you are getting at. Well, I will have the DataTableManager with functions such as DataChanged (a virtual function in the super). But data could have changed in the row or the column. So from there I need to determine the event arg type. (Do you see what I mean?)